# Starting supervisor generates error

Tags: debian, supervisord

For this command: **service supervisor restart** I'm getting this:

```
Restarting supervisor: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/supervisord", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3019, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3003, in _call_aside
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3032, in _initialize_master_working_set
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 657, in _build_master
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 670, in _build_from_requirements
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 849, in resolve
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'supervisor==3.0' distribution was not found and is required by the application
```

and have no idea what to do.
I've upgraded the system using apt-get update and apt-get upgrade and after I started receiving this.

Comment: Did you try to purge supervisor and install it again? After I upgrade to Ubuntu 16.04 I faced with same problem

Comment: yes, I removed and reinstalled it. From it's logs it's the same error.

Comment: Did you install it with pip?

Comment: I've tried with pip, easy_install and apt-get. Similar errors